# How to select pandas rows when a cell value is between two values and the next cell or cells are between the same values?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following pandas dataframe:

```
     Name  speed   
    ---------------
 0   A     100
 1   A     50
 2   A     40
 4   A     30
 5   A     10
 6   B     100
 7   B     50
 8   B     40
 9   B     120
 10  A     10
```

I want to select rows for each name when we find a 10< speed<100 where the next rows speed are also between 10 and 100, until we find  a row with speed=<10 so we select them, if we find a row speed=>100 we don't select them and go on iterating the other rows.  the result should be like this:

```
     Name  speed   
    ---------------
 1   A     50
 2   A     40
 4   A     30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use between() and shift() for this:

```
low = 10
high = 100
mask_next = df.speed.between(low, high, inclusive=False) & (df.speed.shift(-1).between(low, high, inclusive=False))
mask_before = df.speed.between(low, high, inclusive=False) & (df.speed.shift(1).between(low, high, inclusive=False))
df[mask_next | mask_before]
```

Output:

```
    Name    speed
1   A   50
2   A   40
4   A   30
7   B   50
8   B   40
```

If you need it for each name, you have to loop:

```
results = []
for name in df.Name.drop_duplicates().to_list():
    mask_name = df.Name == name
    results.append(df[mask_name & (mask_next | mask_before)])
pd.concat(results)
```

Output:

```
    Name    speed
1   A   50
2   A   40
4   A   30
7   B   50
8   B   40
```

The results are identical with your test data. However, the second approach checks if id 5 and 10 fulfill the condition. The first approach without looping will always drop id 10.

Comment: Thank you Sikan. I appreciate your answer but, that's not what i want exactly, I think I didn't explain it well. my output should not contain rows with id 7 and 8 because the value of id 9 is greater than 100. what i want is for each row i verifiy if the speed is between 10 and 100, if yes we take it and verify the next if it fulfill the condition we take it and so on.. until we find either a value greater than 100(1) or smaller than 10 (2), than we decide like this: if (1) we drop the sequence of rows verifying the condition (10<speed<100), if (2) we mantain it and export it in the output.